# Logging from a DLL in both Windows service and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I've created a .NET DLL which is referenced from a Windows service, windows forms and ASP.NET assemblies.  Included in the DLL is quite a bit of logging to a text log file.  This is straight forward enough from the service and winforms, but obviously not as straight forward trying to write to a log file through ASP.NET.

Can anyone provide some tips on how to go about this?  I want to keep the logging code in the DLL, hence shared between the Windows service and the ASP.NET app.

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea.  What you really ought to do is to create an interface (e.g. `ILogger`) and then make separate concrete implementations for that interface in each project type (ASP and service).  Then, have the appropriate classes in your DLL require an `ILogger` object to be given to them in their constructors.  This is called dependency injection.  Rather than trying to make a magic black box that always works in every situation, which inevitably leads to spaghetti code, with DI, you can reuse the same classes in any situation regardless of how the logging might need to be done.

Comment: +1 to Mr Doggart, my thoughts exactly.

Comment: For instance, what if one day you want one of your services to log to a text file and another service to log to a database or the windows event log, but they both use this same class library which implements its own hidden logging logic.  Suddenly your code gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense.  I avoided interfaces up till now cos I don't quite understand them fully.  Sounds like time for more learning.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a bad idea.  Whenever you try to create black-box type code that just magically works in all situations, it always leads to unmanageable spaghetti code in the long run.  For instance, what if one day you decide that you need two windows services that both use this same common DLL, but one of them needs to log to the windows event log and the other needs to log to a text file.  Now, it's not as easy for your DLL to automatically determine how it should log, and the code gets more messy and complicated.

Dependency Injection (DI) solves these problems very elegantly.  Logging is a separate activity, so it ought to be handled by a separate logger class.  And if logging is handled in its own class, then it becomes a dependency of the other classes that use it.  And classes should not hide their dependencies, but should require them to be "injected" into them.  There are tools and frameworks for doing DI, but simply requesting your dependencies in your constructor is just fine too.

To do it the DI way, you first would need to create an interface for your logger, for instance:

```
Public Interface ILogger
    Sub WriteEntry(message As String)
End Interface
```

Then, in each class that needs to perform logging, you would ask for the logger in the constructor, for instance:

```
Public Class MyBusiness
    Public Sub New(logger As ILogger)
        _logger = logger
    End Sub

    Private _logger As ILogger

    Public Sub DoWork()
        _logger.WriteEntry("Doing work")
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, now you have completely removed any knowledge of the inner workings of logging from your business class, so any class that implements that interface could be given to it and it would still work.  Doing it like this is very freeing.  Now you can reuse that business class in any type of project, no matter what requirements for logging those applications may have.  You might give it a logger that writes to a text file, and event log, a database, the screen, and email, you name it--all without ever touching your business class that uses it.

Now, you can easily create two separate implementations of the `ILogger` interface, one for services and one for ASP.NET sites:

```
Public Class MyAspLogger
    Implements ILogger

    Public Sub WriteEntry(message As String) Implements ILogger.WriteEntry
        ' Do whatever an ASP project must do to log
    End Sub
End Class 

Public Class MyServiceLogger
    Implements ILogger

    Public Sub WriteEntry(message As String) Implements ILogger.WriteEntry
        ' Do whatever a service project must do to log
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then from your ASP project, you could create the business object like this:

```
Dim business As New MyBusiness(New MyAspLogger())
```

And from your service project, you could create it like this:

```
Dim business As New MyBusiness(New MyServiceLogger())
```

Ideally you would create a factory class that creates your business objects for you, so you don't have to manually create a logger (and all your other dependencies) every time you need to create a `MyBusiness` object.

There's no specific implementation requirements for a factory, it's simply a general term to categorize classes.  A factory class would just be any class whose sole/main purpose is to instantiate objects from other classes.  In an ideal world, with DI, you'd never use the `New` keyword anywhere in your code, except in factory classes, but that's not always practical.  Once you start declaring all your dependencies, you'll find that it takes many lines of code to instantiate a single object because you have to first create all the dependencies.  For instance:

```
Dim fileWriter As IFileWriter = New MyFileWriter()
Dim logger As ILogger = New MyServiceLogger(fileWriter)
Dim dataAccess As IDataAccess = New MyDataAccess()
dim business As IBusiness = New MyBusiness(logger, dataAccess)
' Ta da!! I finally have a business object that I can now use
```

So, if you need to create `MyBusiness` objects in multiple places in the same project, that's a lot of copied code.  If for no other reason than for convenience, it makes sense to have a factory, so you can just do this:

```
Dim factory As IBusinessFactory = New MyBusinessFactory()
Dim business As IBusiness = factory.NewMyBusiness()
```

However, there are many other good reasons for making factory classes.  You may need to create multiple loggers, for instance, on demand, inside `MyBusiness`, so in that case, `MyBusiness` couldn't simply ask for a single `ILogger` in its constructor, but it could, instead, ask for an `ILoggerFactory` which implemented a `NewLogger` method.  Then you could have two separate logger factories: one that returns new `MyAspLogger` objects upon request, and one that creates new `MyServiceLogger` objects instead.  So in that way, a factory can, itself, become a dependency of other classes.

Another good reason for factories is because you'll find that the code that instantiates all the objects and wires them all together in different configurations is, in and of itself, a specific kind of business logic which deserves to be separated out in a modular way.

Comment: Steven, thanks.  Finally Interfaces are starting to make sense.  A couple questions if you don't mind me imposing further.  Just to check I got it right: everytime I instantiate a class which uses logging, I need to pass a class to it that implements `iLogger`?  What's a "factory class"?

Comment: The trick is to have each class specify its dependencies as interfaces and ask for them in their constructor.  Once you do that, there will be no way to instantiate an object without providing it with its necessary dependencies.  So yes, if you have a class that asks for an `ILogger`, then every time you create one, you will have to give it an object of some concrete class that implements `ILogger`.

Comment: Got it.  I'll have a go at making it work and let you know how it goes next week sometime .

Comment: If you really get curious and have the time to watch some instructional videos on dependency injection, try searching youtube for some of Misko Hevery's talks on the subject.  He does a great job of explaining things.  Most of all it just takes practice and experience.  The only way to truly learn is to try it.

Comment: I'm working this one through.  My assemblies have quite a lot of shared methods, which also have the ability to log messages.  The dependency injection stuff you explained would work sweet for instantiated classes.  How would this work for shared methods tho?  It seems like the class which implements `iLogger` would need to be passed to each shared method call too for this to work.

Comment: Yeah, shared methods make DI very difficult.  Either you would need to ask for the `ILogger` on each shared method, which would be better, but a huge pain, or you'd need to have a shared initialization method of some sort on each class with shared methods which would take an `ILogger` and store a reference to it in a private shared field of the class.  The problem with that design is that you have to remember to call that init method once at start up before you use any of those shared methods, which is just a bug waiting to happen.