# how to fake a very complicated object for TDD in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, mocking, tdd

Let say I have a class called CIRCLE, and another called SQUARE.
In each of those class, I have a public function called area. (to calculate the
area of the circle, and the area of the square respectively.)

I have also a class iMath. and in this class, I have a function ADD

```
    Public Function ADD(byval c as CIRCLE, byval s as SQUARE) 
       Return c.area() + s.area()
    End Function
```

Now I want to Unit test the ADD function. 
Obviously, for this very easy problem, I can easily create a circle object and a square object to Unit test my ADD function. However, 
let assume that my Circle object and Square object are very complicated objects, very hard to create a object, because they inherit and contains many other dependencies. In such case,

1. How can I fake the CIRCLE and SQUARE objects ? (note: the CIRCLE and SQUARE classes don't have Public Sub New without any parameter in it)
2. How can I fake the results of the area functions the CIRCLE and SQUARE objects (I just need a number to test my ADD function, and I don't care how the areas are calculated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make all of the members of the `CIRCLE` and `SQUARE` classes `Overridable`, then you can inherit them and override all the members with stubs, for instance:

```
Public Class Circle
    Public Overridable Function Area() As Integer
        ' Complicated logic
    End Function
End Class

Public Class MockCircle
    Inherits Circle

    Public Overrides Function Area() As Integer
        Return 10
    End Function
End Class
```

However, if the original `CIRCLE` class requires a bunch of difficult-to-create parameters in its constructor, then that doesn't help you any because the `MockCircle` class will still be required to call the base constructor.

The preferable solution is to use interfaces.  Instead of having your `ADD` method accept a concrete `CIRCLE` object, have it ask for an object that implements an `ICircle` interface instead:

```
Public Interface ICircle
    Function Area() As Integer
End Interface

Public Class Circle
    Implements ICircle

    Public Function Area() As Integer Implements ICircle.Area
        ' Complicated logic
    End Function
End Class

Public Class MockCircle
    Implements ICircle

    Public Function Area() As Integer Implements ICircle.Area
        Return 10
    End Function
End Class

Public Class MyMath
    Public Function Add(c As ICircle, s As ISquare) As Integer
        Return c.Area() + s.Area()
    End Function
End Class
```

Now, it doesn't matter what the `CIRCLE` requires in its constructor because you have taken it entirely out of the equation.  Now, you can give the `ADD` method either a `CIRCLE` object or a `MockCircle` object and it will work either way.  The `MockCircle` object doesn't inherit from `CIRCLE`, so it doesn't share any of its complicated dependencies.  This methodology actually has a convenient name too.  It's called Dependency Injection (DI).  If you are going to be doing a lot of unit testing, it would be well worth your time to do some research on DI.  Ideally, the dependencies for the `CIRCLE` class would also all be done via interfaces as well, so then you could easily create even a `CIRCLE` object by giving it all mock objects for its dependencies as well.

I feel obligated to mention some surface issues with your code too.  For consistency with the .NET framework and Microsoft standards, you should use PascalCase for all of your method and class names.  So for instance, it should be `Add` rather than `ADD`, and it should be `Circle` and `Square` rather than `CIRCLE` and `SQUARE`.  Also, the `iMath` class name should not start with the letter "i".  Putting an "I" at the beginning of a type name, according to Microsoft standards, means that it is an interface, not a class.  The last issue I see is that your `ADD` function does not specify a return type.  You should always specify the return type for all functions.  For instance, in my example, I changed it to return `As Integer`.

Comment: thank you Steven for your advice on the coding style. It is very useful. Regarding to the TDD, if I want to Unit test all functions in a class, says, MyMath Class, from your advice, are you implying that I would have to make the interface for all functions I have?

Comment: Yes, when you are unit testing, it is *MUCH* easier if all public methods are exposed and used via at least one interface.  If you don't do that, it will be far more difficult to implement mock objects for testing.  Besides all the advantages for unit testing, DI, via interfaces, has many other advantages too.  For instance it makes your code more flexible, cleaner, more expandable, less buggy, easier to maintain and refactor, etc.  If you'd like some more examples and introduction on the subject, you could read through some of my other, more in depth answers on the topic.

Comment: [Logging from a DLL in both Windows service and ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13636961/1359668).  [Breaking BLL (Business Logic Layer) to BLL and DAL (Data Access Layer)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14112902/1359668).  [VB.NET What is the purpose of a class or module](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14086535/1359668) (especially the part titled **Provide Seams in Your Code**).  [“Fancy-pants” vs “Cowboy” coding](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/29025/22613)

Comment: Hi Steven, says, I am in team with other developers. I am writing my own class, which calls my team mates' objects. Their class has been designed and implemented without any interfaces. How can I unit test my functions in my own class ?

Comment: There's no magic bullet with unit testing.  If you want to unit test your code, you have to write testable code.  There are products out there that offer the ability to mock any class, even when it doesn't implement an interface, but there's no replacement for good testable code.  If you must, you could write wrapper classes for your teammate's classes.  For instance, you could make an `ICircle` interface and a `MyCircle` class which implements it, and then inside the `MyCircle` class, have it just pass through all the logic to the original `CIRCLE` class.

Comment: Steven, thanks for your very useful articles. Realized that most of your answers are pretty in depth. I just have a final question re this topic. Should every class have its own interface , says, Circle class would have ICircle interface, Square class would have ISquare etc..so that I can unit tests all of my functions in each class ?

Comment: Essentially, yes. At least all business logic classes should have interfaces. Sometimes it makes sense to have multiple classes share the same interface, because they are all the same, but unless making them interchangeable is the purpose of the interface, don't feel obligated to reuse interfaces. If none of the business classes are meant the be interchangeable, it's not at all unreasonable to have a separate interface defined for each one.

Comment: It's admittedly much easier to do when you are writing a new project from scratch. When you are working in existing legacy code, sometimes you can only do things partially right :) But even if you only do things right where you can or where you really need to, you're still better off than doing it all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should rely on existing mocking framework, which exactly solves that problem. One of my favourite one is [NSubsitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/).

It could create mock for any any interface of class with virtual functions. And in general it's more preferable that creating of manual mocks.